# How can 1 port listen to both http and websocket

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, protocols

Hello I have a http server running on port 80. Now as I am new to sockets, I got to know that we can upgrade the connection on the same port and make both work on the same port.

Now I am confused what will happen to the other client.

Consider this:
I send a get request to the server that please upgrade my connection from http to websocket using the same TCP/IP. The server responded with 101. It upgraded the connection. So far so good.

Now the port 80 is a websocket port rather than http. So now, socket.io would be maintaining the connection and request and not the app in express();

So when the next client comes to the same port 80 to do something non-socket related or anything, how the http mechanism would work because the connected is already a socket one now.

How it is doing what it is doing here.

Comment: The next connection is a different connection. You are confusing TCP (transport) connections with application-layer connections. _[RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_ explains: "_To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of addresses or ports within each host.  Concatenated with the network and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection. That is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections._"

Comment: Sir can you please take out some time to elaborate further.

Comment: Your application binds to TCP port 80 to create a socket. A host TCP will connect to your TCP with its own socket. The connection is identified by the pair of sockets. Another host connecting would have its own, different socket, so the pair of sockets would define a different TCP connection. If your TCP socket is A, a host connecting with its socket B would form connection AB. A different host connecting with its socket C would create connection AC. Connection AB is not connection AC. Read the RFC to understand TCP.

Comment: OK sir so I studied the OSI model a bit. So you're telling me that a socket is connection in the session layer. And from that it is distributed in the application layer to the type of protocol? So 1 port can listen to any number of processes

Comment: "_So you're telling me that a socket is connection in the session layer._" No, there is no session layer. Nobody implements the OSI model. TCP is the transport layer, and applications bind to it.

Comment: Sir I wish I could talk to you on discord or something but please tell me what's happening when client pulls up a socket upgrade request. Like everything happening after that. And nobody implements the OSI model? Then what is it? Should I study something else in networking to understand this?

Comment: I gave you a link to the TCP RFC. It has a full explanation of how TCP works (see [Section 2.7 Connection Establishment and Clearing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-2.7)). You should be familiar with how it works before trying to programming with TCP, otherwise you can easily create vulnerabilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231291/discussion-between-shobhit-tewari-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: Every connection is a totally different connection. You can upgrade one, and why would it affect the other ones?

Comment: Please see my updated question and suggest any improvements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the port 80 is a websocket port rather than http.

A TCP listener socket is agnostic to the application protocol. It is only about establishing a new TCP connection. There are not even application data transferred on the listener socket.

Using a specific application protocol like HTTP or switching between application protocols like switching from HTTP to WebSocket, only effects the newly established (accepted) connection but not the listener socket. This also means that it is possible to use different application protocols on different TCP connections, even if all of these connections originated on a single TCP listener socket.

Comment: Okay so that means that my server resides in the application layer and in the session layer, the session is made. After that any process can listen to it with any type of protocol?

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: *"... server resides in the application layer and in the session layer ..."* - kind of. The OSI model you use to distinguish between layer 5..7 does not really reflect today's reality though. More realistic is the TCP/IP model which simply treats everything above the transport layer as application layer - see https://www.guru99.com/tcp-ip-model.html#3 . *"After that any process can listen to it with any type of protocol?"* - yes, there is only TCP socket creation, bind and listen. The application layer happens after the accept on the new connection.

Comment: Here are my conclusions:
1. A socket in TCP is ip address and port bound together to create a unique socket.
2. A connection is set a sockets from both ends for the transmission of data
3. A process is a thread running which is using a connection or in my case, sets a passive open request to the TCP module in my OS.
4. When I asks for upgrading my connection, it is still the same TCP but what happens next is what I am not able to understand.

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: A socket is just a programming abstraction. The concept of processes and threads is irrelevant here - a single process/thread could handle multiple TCP listeners and connection in parallel. The relevant point regarding your original question is that accepting new connections on the listener is just at the transport layer and any application layer stuff is done in the newly accepted connection, independent of the listener and all other connections.

Comment: OK so just 1 clarifying question, if OS allows, any number of different processes or programs can listen on the same port and they uses connections.

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: *"... any number of different processes or programs can listen on the same port ..."* - typically there is only one listener socket for a specific port. This socket might be shared though between different threads and processes. The new connection returned by `accept` is then only handled by one of these processes/threads though, i.e. a random one from all the threads/processes which called `accept` at the same time.

Comment: OK now it may be clear. I get a socket connection and when I do an upgrade request, the connection is updated for a new process which is socket.io listening on the same port? The connection is same it's just the process in the upper layer have changed from app to socket.io

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: There is not a different process involved. This is still the same process, only now interpreting the data in a different way. It's more a different functionality within the same process.

Comment: Please see my updated question and suggest any improvements

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: please don't edit the question significantly after it got answered and answers were accepted. This changes the context of the answer and thus the answer will no longer match the question. I've rolled back your edit because of this. If you want to ask these new questions please make a new question (or several) with enough context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231340/discussion-between-shobhit-tewari-and-steffen-ullrich).